# Right aligning menu buttons not working w3schools

Tags: html, navbar, right-align

I'm trying to use the how to right aligned menu button code from w3schools but the search and about button aren't right aligning. I'm not sure why.

I have copied at the code right from the site and it's not working.

```css
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Right-aligned section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="topnav-right">
        <a href="#search">Search</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float: right` will work

```css
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="topnav-right">
        <a href="#search">Search</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```